# C# - Add chart in Word

Tags: c#, charts, vsto, office-interop

I am working on a VSTO add-in which should be compatible with all version of Word.

I have written following code which adds a chart in Word file.

```
private void AddToNewChart()
{
     // add chart
    Word.Chart chart;
    Word.InlineShape inlineShape;
    string chartType = ((ComboBoxItem)cmbChartType.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();

    if (chartType.Equals("Pie Chart"))
        inlineShape = currDoc.InlineShapes.AddChart(Core.XlChartType.xlPie, Type.Missing);
    else
        inlineShape = currDoc.InlineShapes.AddChart(Core.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered, Type.Missing);

    inlineShape.AlternativeText = newChartName + "__TabularChart";
    chart = inlineShape.Chart;

    // get references
    dynamic chartWB = chart.ChartData.Workbook;
    dynamic chartTable = chartWB.Sheets[1].ListObjects("Table1");
    chartTable.DataBodyRange.ClearContents();
    dynamic chartRange = chartTable.Range.Resize[2, 2];

    // update data
    chartTable.Resize(chartRange);
    chartRange.Cells[chartRange.Rows.Count, 1] = namedRange;
    chartRange.Cells[chartRange.Rows.Count, 2] = excelValue;
    chartRange.Cells[chartRange.Rows.Count, 9] = string.Format("{0}->{1}->{2}", fileId, worksheet, namedRange);

    this.FillChartDropdown();

    chartWB.Close(1);
    chartWB.Application.Quit();
    chartWB.Application = null;
}
```

This works perfectly for **Office 2010**,
but in Office 2013 the Excel process is not terminated at end so so the Word freezes up completely after the chart is added.

So what should I do to terminate Excel process at end?

Comment: What role does the excel process have in this?

Comment: @Chris: When I change Chart source data, Excel is opened automatically. It happens even when we do manually